# Eager loading fields within categories

Tags: categories, eager-loading

Is it possible to eagerLoad fields in categories?

I have this code;

```
{% set markets = craft.categories.group({
  section: 'markets',
  with: ['bannerImage']
}) %}
```

which for some reason is throwing an error;

> mb_convert_case() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Is this a bug or something bad in my code? Removing the with call and it renders fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically just a syntax error. What you are doing is: searching for entries in the group `section: 'markets', with: ['bannerImage']` but what you want is searching for categories in the group `markets` with the field `bannerImage`

```
{% set markets = craft.categories.group('markets').with(['bannerImage']).all() %}
```

The `group` parameter in your `CategoryQuery` defined which group(s) you want to select. The `with` parameter your eager-loading elements. Btw: `Categories` have no `section` property